# How enable Mongo auditing for Spring via yaml?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mvc

I am trying use `@CreatedBy` in a Spring Boot project with MongoDB. The app don't use Spring xml configuration file, so I cannot add `mongo:auditing` to Spring configuration. It uses an `applicantion.yml` file.

I use `@EnableMongoAuditing` on the main Application class and other features such as `@CreatedDate` and `@LastModifiedDate` works correctly. In addition I have a `SecurityAuditorAware implements AuditorAware<User>` but I guess this should be declared on yaml in the same way on XML configuration. How can I use this AuditorAware via yaml?

Answer (score 0):

The Java Config equivalent to XML's `<mongo:auditing auditor-aware-ref="securityAuditorAware" />` would be `@EnableMongoAuditing(auditorAwareRef = "securityAuditorAware")`. I guess you're midsing the `auditorAwareRef` attribute

Just make sure your AuditorAware implementation is a Bean with either `@Bean("securityAuditorAware")`

```
@Bean("securityAuditorAware")
public SecurityAuditorAware securityAuditorAware(){
   return new SecurityAuditorAware();
}
```

or `@Component("securityAuditorAware")` Class level.

```
@Component("securityAuditorAware")
public class SecurityAuditorAware implements AuditorAware<User> {...}
```

You can't configure it in a properties or yaml file.